# Variable shift for a function of n variables

Tags: recursion, variable-definitions

I have a polynomial in `n` variables, `L[1]`,...,`L[n]`. Starting from an index j, I want to shift the variables of the polynomial like: `L[i]->L[i+1]`, from `i=j` to `i = n`, simultaneously. So for example `L[1]+ L[3]^2 -> L[2]+L[4]^2`

This is part of a recursion, so `n` and `j` will be positive integers, but I would like to define this operation for arbitrary `n` and `j`.

I have tried using "\." and loops but I haven't yet figured out how to avoid shifting variables that I have already shifted. Also, I suspect/hope there is a much better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClearAll[shift]
shift[p_, k_] := p /. L[i_ /; i >= k] :> L[i + 1]
```

Example:

```
n = 7;
poly = RandomInteger[9, n]. Array[L, n]^RandomInteger[{1, 9}, n]
```

> 5 L[1]^9 + 9 L[2]^8 + 4 L[3]^6 + 4 L[4]^3 + 8 L[5]^6 + 4 L[6]

```
shift[poly, 4]
```

> 5 L[1]^9 + 9 L[2]^8 + 4 L[3]^6 + 4 L[5]^3 + 8 L[6]^6 + 4 L[7]